# Populate html.DropDownList with File Names Using GetFiles or EnumarateFiles

Tags: asp.net, razor, html-helper

I'm trying to create a very simple **HTML.DropDownList** of files. I'm getting some Invalid arguments error. I've tried both GetFiles() and EnumerateFiles() methods. I believe I have an IEnumerable problem.  I'm using WebMatrix/ WebPages/ C#. Thanks.

```
 // DirectoryInfo directory = new DirectoryInfo(Server.MapPath("Images/Products"));
 // var filesListing = directory.GetFiles().ToList<FileInfo>();
 var filesListing = Directory.EnumerateFiles("Images/Products");

 @Html.DropDownList("Files",filesListing)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Server.MapPath if it's a virtual directory...

```
var filesListing = Directory.EnumerateFiles(Server.MapPath("Images/Products"));
@Html.DropDownList("Files",filesListing)
```

Comment: Thanks. I used your filesListing statement and still got the invalid arguments error.

Answer (score 0):

There is simply no such overload for [DropDownList](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.selectextensions.dropdownlist%28v=vs.118%29.aspx). You need to construct a `SelectList` object using the file list:

```
var filesListing = new SelectList(Directory.EnumerateFiles("Images/Products"));
```

Make sure to add `using System.Web.Mvc;` to the code file. There is no need to change the view code if you do the change above.

Comment: Thanks, I got a missing Directive message for the SelectList; which one should I add ?

Comment: @Edgy the answer with this bit

Comment: Thanks,   Ok, I added "@using System.Web.Mvc;"  to my test.cshtml page, but still getting missing directive message... AND I am not using MVC, thanks..

Comment: @Edgy not using MVC means? are you using asp.net only?

Comment: I'm using Webmatrix Webpages (?), razor....C#.  so, definitely not using MVC coding...Thanks..